# How to iterate over function arguments and modify values if null

Tags: php

I want to convert all parameters to empty string when NULL is passed. Something like this, but the original value of the parameters is not changed in my code.

```
function loopThroughArgs($a, $b) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach ($args as &$arg) {
        $arg = $arg === null ? "" : $arg;
    }
    
    var_dump($a); // should output an empty string
    var_dump($b); // should output an empty string

}

$a = null;
$b = null;

loopThroughArgs($a, $b);
```

Comment: It has a copy of those arguments. So, even if you used an `&`, you are simply modifying the copy only without creating copy of the copy. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php#refsect1-function.func-get-args-returnvalues

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my point. The original variables should be modified.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I mentioned. `func_get_args()` only has copy of those arguments. It won't change your `$a` and `$b` parameters.

Comment: This is my question, if this is possible to change the parameters. It's not possible, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `func_get_args()` returns a copy of those arguments, it won't automatically change your function parameter variables.

---

You can use [`get_defined_vars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) to reassign values. Loop over all declared variables and assign values to each of them from your `$args`. If the variable name would have been something different apart from `args`, that name will come in your `if` condition.

```
<?php

function loopThroughArgs($a, $b) {
    $vars = get_defined_vars();
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach ($args as &$arg) {
        $arg = $arg === null ? "" : $arg;
    }
    
    $ptr = 0;
    
    foreach($vars as $key => $val){
      ${$key} = $args[$ptr++];
    }
    
    var_dump($a); // should output an empty string
    var_dump($b); // should output an empty string

}

$a = null;
$b = null;

loopThroughArgs($a, $b);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/php/3ywq38a22)

Comment: Since get_defined_vars () only gets the variables at the point you call the function, if it is called right at the beginning of the function, it should only return the arguments that are passed to the function, right? In this case, your code could be simplified:

function loopThroughArgs($a, $b) {
    $vars = get_defined_vars();
    foreach ($vars as $key => $val) {
        $$key = $val === null ? "" : $val;
    }
}

Comment: @smolo Nice simplification suggestion, updated the answer.

Comment: Is it necessary to call func_get_args() if you can assume that both functions return the same values if called at the beginning of a function?

Comment: @smolo This is opinion based. IMO, I would still use func_get_args() as it is a defined standard way of getting the function arguments, plus avoids the need to rewrite anything given the get_defined_vars() is called anywhere in the code and not necessarily on the first line of the function.

Comment: In my case, get_defined_vars() is called right on the first line of the function and therefore my slimmed-down code will suffice.

Comment: @smolo Fair enough, you can go with that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand why you require a dynamic solution with your example.

If you want to null coalesce variables in your function scope, then do this explicitly when/where needed.

```
function loopThroughArgs($a, $b) {
    var_dump($a ?? '');
    var_dump($b ?? '');
}
```

If you use a given variable more than once, I can see the need to update it -- use null coalescing assignments.

```
function loopThroughArgs($a, $b) {
    $a ??= '';
    $b ??= '';
    var_dump($a);
    var_dump($b);
}
```

I mean, the function signature is hardcoded, so you already know which variables are possible.

I suppose only if you have a large number of incoming nullable strings as individual parameters and writing each assignment would consume 10 or more lines, *maybe* you'd benefit from a dynamic solution.

1. Access the defined variables in your function scope,
2. Null coalesce each value to an empty string,
3. Use `extract()` to overwrite the parameter values -- ensuring no `null` values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WGsQ0))

```
function loopThroughArgs($a, $b) {
    extract(
        array_map(
            fn($v) => $v ?? '',
            get_defined_vars()
        )
    );
    
    var_dump($a);
    var_dump($b);
}
```

Or with variable variables ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9Vvft))

```
function loopThroughArgs($a, $b) {
    foreach (get_defined_vars() as $k => $v) {
        $$k = $v ?? '';
    }
    
    var_dump($a);
    var_dump($b);
}
```